# Make UIView pass through touch events?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

Is there a way to make a UIView unresponsive AND pass through all touch events? Basically I just want to display graphics on top of other UIViews without blocking touch events.

Comment: Magic Bullet Dave actually provided a correct answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026097/passing-through-touches-to-uiviews-underneath

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The event sent to your view will go through the responder chain, if it doesn't implement any event handling method.

You could also set the `userInteractionEnabled` property to `NO` for that view.

Comment: You're right. I actually meant to ask something else, but realized I was doing it the wrong way, so my real question is now moot..