# Pass click on UIScrollView to the Cell below it

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have TableView and I'm placing UIScrollView with images inside every cell.
My problem is, when I click the UIScrollView, the code that should run on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not running.

I know why, but I don't know how to pass the click to the relevant cell.
I tried using TAG so `self.scrollViewer.tag = [indexPath row];` ' and adding `UITapGestureRecognizer` for every scrollView, but it's not accurate... somtimes it loads the data of the previous or next cell...

if the previous or next cell is little showing a little bit, the tag changes.. so I have to be exactly on the current cell for the correct tag.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is [pointInside, hitTest:withEvent](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/pointInside:withEvent)

This [thread will likely help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026097/passing-through-touches-to-uiviews-underneath).

Comment: You seem to suggest that the scrollView is intercepting the tap that would normally be received by the row. The thread I linked to includes discussion on how to pass a tap through a view (UIScrollView) to another (row). Though doing so would likely prevent the user from interacting with the scrollView (i.e. scrolling it).