# iOS: Is it possible to interact with a view while another view is on top?

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard

I have a mapview, and I have another collectionView on top of the mapview. Is it possible to interact with the mapView(drag around) while the the collectionView is on top?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing through touches to UIViews underneath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026097/passing-through-touches-to-uiviews-underneath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the collectionView has its user interaction boolean set to NO then the touches should pass thru to the map view.