# Can not trigger the event of collectionview when add tapGestureRecognizer to its backgroundview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer

1. Add a collectionview into a view Add the view into a
2. backgroundview(UIView)
3. Add tapGestureRecognizer to the backgroundView

The select event of collectionview can not be triggered when tap a cell,It always trigger the tap event of backgroundview

```
let backgroundView = UIView(frame: sender.window!.bounds)
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    let blueView = BlueView(frame: CGRect(x: 300, y: 200, width: 300, height: 400))
    backgroundView.addSubview(blueView)
    sender.window!.addSubview(backgroundView)
    backgroundView.userInteractionEnabled = true

    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: blueView, action: "tapGestureRecognizer")
    gesture.delegate = blueView
    backgroundView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

..........

```
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 0, width: 100, height: 340), collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cv.dataSource = self

    blueView.addSubview(cv)
```

Who know the reason?

Comment: If I am right, the Gestures you add to the superview will affect the subviews as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that adding a `UIGestureRecognzer` to the `superview` affects the touch events in its `subview`s as well. To avoid that, you need to implement the following delegate method of `UIGestureRecognzer` and negate the `UIGestureRecogniser`'s touch action by returning `false`.

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool
{
    var view = gestureRecognizer.view
    if view.tag != 100 //Set a tag for the backgroundview
    {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

**EDIT**

Looking through your code, I doubt you haven't set the `UICollectionView`'s delegate. You have just set the `DataSource`. The `didselect` method is a delegate method, not dataSource. Try adding the following right below you set the `UICollectionView`'s `dataSource`:

```
cv.delegate= self
```

Comment: Where did you implement the delegate method?

Comment: I implement the delegate for in the class which contains gesture.delegate = self. And it it called actually and return false when tap a cell, but it does not trigger the didselect event of collection view

Answer (score 0):

I think that you answered your question.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

It's a delegate method from `UICollectionView`, so when you make a `UIView` with recognizer inside cell it takes the touches and won't pass them through and so collection view won't call its delegate methods.

If you want possible solutions, there are a lot:

1) If you need only custom logic inside your cell, when somebody clicked cell, you can just override `selected` inside cell and add your logic here:

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override var selected: Bool {
        didSet {

        }
    }
}
```

2) You can create delegate method that is called from your tap recognizer selector or notification:

```
func tapGestureRecognizer() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("TappedRecognizer", object: nil)
}

class YourController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "tappedRecognizer", name: "TappedRecognizer", object: nil)
    }

    func tappedRecognizer() {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

3) I suppose its possible to pass your touches through your view to cell, so it will call delegate method of `UICollectionView`, then you should override `pointInside` method for `UITapGestureRecognizer`, you can search a lot of code on this topic, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026097/passing-through-touches-to-uiviews-underneath)

Comment: I do not make a UIView with recognizer inside cell