# Forward touches to UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a container view that contains the view of a `UIPageViewController`. This is inside a `UIViewController` and takes up the whole screen. On top of the container view I have a `UIView`, covering half the screen, which contains a button and some text. I want to forward the touches from this `UIView` to the `UIPageViewController`. This is so that the `UIPageViewController` can still be swiped left/right even if the user is swiping over the `UIView`. I also want the button to be able to be pressed, therefore can't just set isUserInteractionEnabled to false on the `UIView`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing through touches to UIViews underneath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026097/passing-through-touches-to-uiviews-underneath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[hitTest](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest?language=objc) is the method which determines who should consume the touches/gestures.

So your "`UIView`, covering half the screen" can subclass from say `NoTouchHandlerView` like. And then this view will not consume touches. It would pass then to views under it.

```
class NoTouchHandlerView: UIView
{
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?
    {
        if let hitTestView = super.hitTest(point, with: event), hitTestView !== self {
            return hitTestView
        }else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This `NoTouchHandlerView` does have a `UIButton` in though, will this disable the `UIButton`?

Answer (score 0):

Objective C version of the accepted answer for lazy guys like me :)

```
@implementation NoTouchHandlerView

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView* hitTestView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    if (hitTestView != nil && hitTestView != self) {
        return hitTestView;
    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```