# How to delegate touch events from top viewcontroller to bottom viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, touch-event

I have a map viewcontroller **A** and another viewcontroller **B** on top of **A**. I made viewcontroller **B** a transparent background to see the map in **A**. Between the navbar and bottom toolbar of **B**, I want to be able to move the map in **A**. The problem is, the touches in **B** doesn't arrive on Viewcontroller **A**. How can I make it possible to delegate the touches from **B** to **A**?
I've seen examples based on UIView, but it didn't work for me so far.

Here is an image for a visual presentation:

[image]

The red arrows are the touch events I want to pass through to the underlying ViewController **A**.

I tried the solution in [on this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9031558/1012775)
but that didn't work for me. Whatever I tried, ViewController **A** doesn't receive the touch events if ViewController **B** is on top of it. I hope you can help me out on this one.

Comment: What **B** does? Any user interaction controls there which should remain working (respond to touches) or should it _pass_ all touches, ...?

Comment: It should pass touches in some area in ViewController B, like between navbar and bottom toolbar, to ViewController A.

Comment: One more question - how is the view controller **B** presented? Is it a child view controller of **A**? Is it a modal over **A**? How the whole view hierarchy looks like?

Comment: ViewController is presented as a Modal viewcontroller by using:  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueViewControllerB" sender: self]; It's ViewController over another ViewController, whether it's modal or not, it doesn't matter imo.