# Zooming Image When Pinched On A Non-ScrollView Entity/Sub-entity

Tags: ios

I am implementing cropping feature from scratch, which has the following structure

```
                                BaseUIView
                                 /    \
                                /      \
                               /        \
                              /          \
              CropUIView,EdgeUIView     ScrollView
                                           |
                                           |
                                           |
                                        ImageView
```

I have a couple of cropping handles which can be dragged to enlarge/diminish the cropping window (i.e. change the size of CropUIView and EdgeUIView accordingly).

I have kept the CropUIView hidden so that I can provide Pinch-Zoom feature for the image in the ImageView. Currently, I am dependent on the ScrollView and its delegates to help scroll/zoom the image.

What I need to implement is, when the user pinches on the EdgeUIView (the greyed area as shown in the image below), the image should zoom in/out the way it does when I pinch on the clear area.

I am aware that this kind of functionality may not make sense.

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Why you decided to refuse from scrollView?

Comment: The scrollView works perfectly fine, however, since the scrollView is below the edgeView, it doesn't receive the touch and the scroll/zooming doesn't work.

Comment: What if you subclass efgeView from scrollView or make it conform to UISCrollview delegate?

Comment: If I were you, I'd drop the UIScrollView and implement pinch zoom and touch scroll functions in the BaseUIView (or derived custom view) class. It would require under 300 lines of code.

Comment: Also look at this link about forwarding touch events http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834301/ios-forward-all-touches-through-a-view

Comment: @Roma, Then the edgeView would zoom along with the image. I'll look into the forwarding of touch events' link.

Comment: @9dan, simulating pinch-zoom would be an overkill.

Comment: @AkashKothawale Also you can look on some ready solutions. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=crop. You can look how other did this and replicate behaviour on EdgeView

Comment: Got the answer. Disabled `userInteraction` for the EdgeView. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the structure of my UIViews is messed up, but the solution that worked, comes from:
[Make UIView pass through touch events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662468/make-uiview-pass-through-touch-events).

I simply had to disable user interaction on the EdgeView to make the touch events pass through.